# Splitting a string that contains multiple values

Tags: c#

I have a string which contains 3 Id's in it which are concatenated together using "-".
for eg it will be always "name-someId-variableName". I want to split it into name, someId and Variable name, but the issue is that the id can either be xxxxx or xx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx.

currently I am splitting them, and then counting them and storing them.

```
List<string> list1= new List<string>();
List<string> idList= concatenatedId.Split('-').ToList();
If(idList.count==7)
{
list1.Add(idList[0]);
list1.Add(idList[1]+'-'+idList[2]+'-'+idList[3]+'-'+idList[4]+'-'+idList[5]);
list1.Add(idList[6])
}
else if(idlist.count==3)
{
list1.Add(idList[0]);
list1.Add(idList[1]);
list1.Add(idList[2]);
}
return list1;
```

Is there any efficient or better way of doing this?

Comment: Why use ToList on the array?

Comment: so your *separator* is `-`, and also your *data* can contain `-` unescaped... how do you think your code ought to know the difference? your absolutely best bet would be to try and fix the input format. otherwise you can only hope you never encounter variables with unexpected hyphens.

Comment: I can not change the input format.It's being used in a lot of other places

Comment: then i rcommend looking at those other places and implementing your parsing the same way. (then unifying them into a single parsing function. then simultaneously fixing the format and updating that function.)

Comment: `If` is not valid C#, `idList.count` (with `idlist` being a `List<string>`) is not valid C#. `concatenatedId` is never initialized. Please [edit] to a [mre].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Contrary to paul's answer, I wouldn't use a regular expression.
IMHO, Except in very particular cases, regular expressions adds complexity to the code, because they're not as readable as plain c#.

I would probably write it like this (note: I'm returning an array, not a list, but it's easy to change if you need a list):

```
string[] SpecialSplit(string concatenatedId)
{
    var splitted = concatenatedId.Split('-', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    return splitted.Length == 7
        ? new []
            {
                splitted[0],
                string.Join('-', splitted.Skip(1).Take(5)),
                splitted[6]
            }
        : splitted;
}
```

Comment: From the readability point, this looks even better then using ranges and slices.

Comment: @PatrickArtner I believe that's just because the range index thing is new in c#. Once we get to use it long enough, using `splitted[0..1]` will probably feel as natural as using `splitted[0]`... that would probably be around when they release the beta of c# 10, though :-)

Comment: @ZoharPeled Agreed, I too think, that it's more a matter of how used we are to ranges and indices.

Answer (score 2):

With [C# 8.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8) you can use [ranges and indexes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8#indices-and-ranges) to slice your data to your liking:

Example that would always extract the first and last split and rejoin the middle ones even if not exactly 7 pieces were split:

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var text = "abcdef-ghi-jkl-mno-pqr-stu-vwxyz";

        var splitted = text.Split('-');

        var start  = splitted[0..1];    // first element
        var middle = splitted[1..^1];   // all middle elements, however many there are
        var end    = splitted[^1..];    // last element

        Console.WriteLine(text);
        Console.WriteLine($"'{string.Join("','",splitted)}'");
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join('-',start));
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join('-',middle));
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join('-',end));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
// input text
abcdef-ghi-jkl-mno-pqr-stu-vwxyz
// splits
'abcdef','ghi','jkl','mno','pqr','stu','vwxyz'
// [0..1]
abcdef
// [1..^1]
ghi-jkl-mno-pqr-stu
// [^1..]
vwxyz
```

joined if needed:

```
var joined_middle = string.Join('-', middle);
```

Comment: Can't wait for the upgrade in my company... some of us are still working with c#6...

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what characters are allowed for the name and the variable name, I'd go with the regular expression

```regex
^([a-zA-Z\d]+)\-([a-zA-Z\-\d]+)\-([a-zA-Z\d]+)$
```

The term `[a-zA-Z\d]+` matches at least one (upper or lower) character or number of the name, then the term `([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+)` matches at least one (upper or lower) character, digit or `-` for the ID and then the first term is used again for the variable name. The parts are separated by dashes (`\-`).

By using case-independent regexes (as proposed by Zohar in the comments), the expression could be simplified to

```regex
^([a-z\d]+)\-([a-z\-\d]+)\-([a-z\d]+)$
```

Anyway, the presented pattern would match a---b as well. If you'd like to (or you are not sure enough that there won't be any malformed IDs) you could use

```regex
([a-z\d]{5}|[a-z\d]{2}\-[a-z\d]{4}\-[a-z\d]{4}\-[a-z\d]{4}\-[a-z\d]{4})
```

for the middle term. This would either match 5 characters or digits (or any combination) or rows of 2, 4, 4, 4 and 4 characters or digits separated by dashes.

To separate the values in C# you could then use `Regex.Match` and access the groups

```
var input = "test-12-1234-1234-1234-1234-abc";
var pattern = @"^([a-z\d]+)\-([a-z\d]{5}|[a-z\d]{2}\-[a-z\d]{4}\-[a-z\d]{4}\-[a-z\d]{4}\-[a-z\d]{4})\-([a-z\d]+)$";

var match = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(input, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

if(match.Success)
{
    var name = match.Groups[1].Value;
    var id = match.Groups[2].Value;
    var variable = match.Groups[3].Value;
    
    // Do whatever you want to with the values
}
```

Comment: Free tip: Use [the overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.match?view=netcore-3.1#System_Text_RegularExpressions_Regex_Match_System_String_System_String_System_Text_RegularExpressions_RegexOptions_) that takes in a member of `RegexOptions` to simplify your regular expressions. Instead of `[a-zA-Z\d]` you can write `[a-z\d]` - making the entire regular expression that much smaller and easier to read, understand and maintain.

Answer (score -2):

Not that I'm fan of the solution, but you could try regular expressions.

There are 2 downsides:

1. It's not necessarily more efficient, but it can be nicer.
2. There's an old saying: "I had a problem. I used regular expression. No I have two problems."